# How to disable a command with argument?

Tags: macros, tex4ht

I had to remove the `caption` package when compiling with `tex4ht` after finding problems with it in tex4ht mode only.

So I edited my main include tex file and did the following

```
\ifdefined\HCode %do not load caption package in tex4ht mode
\else 
\usepackage{caption}% use only with lualatex and pdflatex
\fi
```

But since I already used it and have lots of code which uses it like this

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}    
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{problems/p1} 
\caption{problem 1 description}%
\end{figure}
```

Now the above will not compile in tex4ht mode since tex4ht does not know what `\captionsetup` set up is which comes from the `caption` package.

I do not want to manually edit all the files I happened to have used the above in, and change each such case like the above to the following

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\ifdefined\HCode 
\else 
\captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth} 
\fi 

\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{problems/p1} 

\caption{problem 1 description}%
\end{figure}
```

So I changed my main tex include file again to redefine `\captionsetup` to be nothing when in tex4ht mode, like this

```
  \ifdefined\HCode %disable caption
      \newcommand{\captionsetup}{} 
  \else 
      \usepackage{caption}
  \fi
```

But the above did not work. Now when I compile with tex4ht, I get error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
}
l.52 \captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}
```

What would be the correct way to disable such a command that takes arguments like this so I do not have to edit all the latex file by hand?

TL 2020 on Linux.

Comment: \newcommand\captionsetup[1]{}

Comment: In more detail: ```\ifdefined\HCode %do not load caption package in tex4ht mode
\else 
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\captionsetup[1]{} \fi```

Comment: If you need to handle spaces after the argument I suggest this: `\makeatletter`...`\ifdefined\HCode\newcommand\captionsetup[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}\else\usepackage{caption}\fi`...`\makeatother`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, but if somebody uses `\captionsetup` in the middle of a paragraph, they deserve no sympathy. `;-)`

Comment: @Andrew The command `\cptionsetup` gets defined by the `caption`-package so it cannot be correct to define it via `\newcommand` in the same situation where the package is loaded....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX4ht now handles the Caption package, so you don't need to disable it. The following example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=.8\textwidth}    
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image.png} 
  \caption{problem 1 description}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]